# Angular 2 call function with subscribe inside a for loop

Tags: angular

I have a function with subscription to a service inside:

```
selectCar(carNumber) {
  this.carService.getCarByNumerator(carNumber)
    .subscribe( (car) => {
                  console.log(carNumber);
                  //more stuff here
                },
                (err) => console.log(err)
               );
}
```

I want to call this function inside a for loop as following:

```
for(let carNumber of carNumbers) {
    this.selectCar(carNumber);
}
```

The issue is, sometime it works as I expect, but sometimes the order is not as in the list.

E.g. the list is:

```
45
67
89
```

but when I look in the console, I see the following:

```
67
89
45
```

How can I force the for loop not to go to next item till the current function call finished?

Comment: you can change your function to a recursive one,that will help but cost of that will increase.

Comment: Asynchronous calls are being made to an API/backend, you can't guarantee data will be returned in a specific order. Can you simply sort/order the results before additional processing/display? Otherwise you can consider operators such as [combineAll](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/combineAll.ts) or [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md)

Answer (score 8):

If you need to effectively wait for all `getCarByNumerator()` to complete prior to processing your list of data, you can use the [forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) operator.

```
let carNumbers = [1, 2, 3];
let observables = carNumbers.map(carNumber => this.carService.getCarByNumerator(carNumber));

// forkJoin the array/collection of observables
let source = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(observables);

// subscribe and sort combined array/collection prior to additional processing
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

Here is [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/lipimuqino/edit?html,console) demonstrating the functionality. The example demonstrates varying delays for returning data from the "API".

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you, you saved my day

Answer (score 2):

I guess `flatMap` would help you in this case.

```
Observable.of(carNumbers)
.flatMap(term => this.selectCar(term))
.subscribe( (car) => {
        console.log(carNumber);
        //more stuff here
    },
    (err) => console.log(err)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 2 questions about it: 1. seems that the content of selectCar will occur twice, no? as you both call it and later do the stuff of it again. 2. If I try this, I get an error in the part that I am trying to send term to the selectCar. It says that it accept a single car number but gets a whole array. what it the term type? one item of the array or all array?